# What is the difference in these two ES6 arrow functions in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

If I click a button, it calls `handleClick` which increases the value of the button by 1 from 0.
I have made the `handleClick` code work in two different scenarios. I understand the first, I don't seem to grasp the second one.

**I wrote this one. And it works.**

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})
  }
```

**The tutorial shows this one and it works too.**

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(({count}) => ({
      count: count + 1
    }))
  }
```

**If I change the code to this, this works too.**

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    }))
  }
```

What is the advantage of using the second body of code when it does the same thing but is more complex than the first one?

I understand I am returning an object literal which is basically what I wrote instead of generating it in the first code body. But why am I passing `{count}` as a parameter when I can keep the parameter empty and just use `this.state.count` in the body?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661166/what-do-function-parameter-lists-inside-of-curly-braces-do-in-es6

Comment: @epascarello Thanks. Is state automatically passed to the function? Because if I understand correctly I have to pass the object to the function if I don't destructure. But I'm passing no parameters when i access count from `this.state.count`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In React, `this.setState()` queues the change. It is not guaranteed to happen right away. So the value of `this.state.count` may have changed by the time `setState` actually makes the change.

In the second version, you're passing a function to `this.setState()`. When React is ready to change the state, that function is called, with the current state as an argument. This lets you ensure that the state is incremented correctly.

[The React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) goes into more detail.