# Understanding arrow function in typescript

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions

I am trying to understand arrow functions in typescript at [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
var elements = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

elements.map(function(element) { 
  return element.length; 
}); // [8, 6, 7, 9]

elements.map(element => {
  return element.length;
}); // [8, 6, 7, 9]

elements.map(element => element.length); // [8, 6, 7, 9]

elements.map(({ length }) => length); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

I understood all except the last line. In the second last line, it accepts a single expression and returns `element.length`. Equivalent to `{return element.length;}`. But the last statement makes no sense to me.

Things that I don't understand:

1. It is taking an object `length`.
2. If it is single argument, why is it in `()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do function parameter lists inside of curly braces do in es6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661166/what-do-function-parameter-lists-inside-of-curly-braces-do-in-es6)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at that last line:

```
elements.map(({ length }) => length); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

there are curly braces `{`, `}` around the `length` argument.

It's called Object destructuring assignment:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Answer (score 0):

Map is destructuring the parameter which is passed to it. A string is passed to the map function in this case, and a string has many properties, one of which is length. So the string is destructured and its property, length, is set to the destructured length variable. 
+1 to JulianG...