# Destructured object as function parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I don’t understand the parameter of `const Posts` below. I’m fairly new to node/React. Is it a destructured parameter object? Or is it just an object being passed as a parameter?

getPosts and post are showing as undefined. But I don’t understand where the parameter object is being passed from into the function...

Full code here: https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector_2.0/blob/master/client/src/components/posts/Posts.js

Thanks in advance!!

````
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
import PostForm from './PostForm';
import { getPosts } from '../../redux/actions/post';

const Posts = ({ getPosts, post: { posts, loading } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, [getPosts]); ```
````

Comment: Yes, it's a function expecting an object, and destructuring that in its parameter declaration.

Comment: "*But I don’t understand where the parameter object is being passed from into the function...*" - have a look at the code that *calls* `Posts`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So `Posts` is a [React Function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components).

All Function components will receive a props object as its first argument.

```js
const Posts = (props) => { /* ... */ }
```

props will always be an object containing the props that were passed into it when the component was rendered, for example:

```
import Posts from './path/to/Posts'

function SomeParentComponent() {
  return <Posts limit={10} categories={{news:true, sports:false}} />
}
```

In this case `props` will be an object that looks like this:

```js
{
  limit : 10,
  categories : {
    news : true,
    sports : false,
  }
}
```

You can of course destructure the props object in your component:

```js
const Posts = (props) => {
  const { 
   limit,
   categories
  } = props
  // ... other stuff
}
```

But you can go even further and do what's called "unpacking" in order to destructure nested properties

```js
const Posts = (props) => {
  const { 
   limit,
   categories : {
     sports,
     news
   }
  } = props
  // ... other stuff
}
```

Lastly, instead of doing that in the function body, you can destructure and unpack objects in-line where the arguments are for the same result.

```js
const Posts = ({limit, categories:{news,sports}}) => {
  // ... other stuff
}
```

Which is what your code sample is doing.

It appears it's expecting the parent component to pass in a function as the `getPosts` prop, which when called will first set `posts.loading` to true, load the posts, then set `posts.loading` to false. Ex:

```js
function SomeParentComponent() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  const loadPosts = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    const loadedPosts = await loadPostsSomehow()
    setPosts([posts, ...loadedPosts])
    setLoading(false)
  }, [])
  return <Posts getPosts={loadPosts} post={{posts, loading}} />
}
```

*Make sure to use `useCallback` to get a memoized callback here or you will get stuck in an infinite loop*

**EDIT**

After actually looking at the link provided, it's slightly different actually. Instead of the `post` object being provided by the parent component, it's actually provided by redux, but the logic is essentially the same. The difference is that instead of the parent component changing the loading and post state, it's done via redux state management.

Comment: Brilliant answer - totally explains it. Thanks so much! I spent hours trying & failing to understand it.

Comment: I don’t recommend to destructure and unpack objects in-line where the arguments are, as you may need to have access to whole props Object, e.g. pass all props to the children using {...props}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is de-structured function parameter object.

In your case parameters to `Posts` pass through [Redux connect()](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) function.

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPosts }
)(Posts);
```

Check your `getPosts` import and make sure it is not `undefined`.

```
import { getPosts } from '../../actions/post';
```

Also check your redux state and make sure it has `state.post`.

Comment: Ah... forgot to add posts to the root reducer (reducers/index.js).  So much harder to debug React/node than php!

Comment: Yes, it is confusing at the beginning. But On the big application you will come to appreciate React with Redux setup if you embrace it.