# Are Javascript Objects similar to Python functions?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I've learned python and right now I am beginning to learn javascript. I've got a question about Javascript objects.

```
var superSecureTerminal = {
        allUserNames: [],
        _username: "",
        ...}
```

Are the allUserNames and _username arguments of the object? In python would it be similar to

`def superSecureTerminal(allUserNames, _username):`

Comment: No, objects do not have arguments, only properties. A function is quite distinct from an object

Comment: ...but JS objects themselve can be arguments to JS functions - and a recently-added feature of JS is auto-destructuring objects to parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661166/what-do-curly-braces-inside-of-function-parameter-lists-do-in-es6

Comment: A javascript object is like a python dictionary.

Comment: The Python code would be almost identical to the JS code, except without the `var` keyword. And you need to quote the dictionary keys in Python.

Answer (score 1):

JS objects are most like Python dictionaries. That JS code is equivalent to the Python

```
superSecureTerminal = {
    "allUserNames": [],
    "_username": "",
    ...
}
```

However, JS objects also have prototypes that can be used like classes are used in Python. EcmaScript 6 added `class` declarations that create the prototypes automatically, so the code can be organized similarly to the way you write classes in Python and PHP.