# Confused about de-structuring function parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

In the following example why does the whois() function have access to displayName2 and name1?

```js
function whois({displayName: displayName2, fullName: {firstName: name1}}){
  console.log(`${displayName2} is ${name1}`)
}

let user = {
  displayName: "jdoe",
  fullName: {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe"
  }
}
whois(user) // "jdoe is John"
```

To the untrained eye it looks like it should have access to displayName and fullName.firstName. The destructuring looks like JSON in reverse.

What's happening under the hood?

Comment: The parameters the function will have access to are those at the right side of the colon (`:`), and only at the deepest nesting level of the object notation. In this case `displayName2` and `name1` are the only variables that are created there.

Comment: Well yes, [that's destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10804982/1048572). And it does indeed work like object literals in reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`displayName` and `firstName` were [assigned new names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) - `displayName2` and `firstName1` receptively, and to access the values, you need to use the alias.

Since only the aliases are defined as variables, trying to access the values using the old names, will throw a "variable is not defined" error.

```js
const destructure1 = ({ a: aa }) => console.log(aa);
destructure1({ a: 5 }); // gets the value

const destructure2 = ({ a: aa }) => console.log(a);
destructure2({ a: 5 }); // throw an error because a is not defined
```

In addition, when using destructuring with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), you must assign it to a new variable name:

```js
const prop = 'a';

const destructure1 = ({ [prop]: aa }) => console.log(aa);
destructure1({ a: 5 }); // gets the value
```

Comment: I see thanks. It does look like JSON but it really isn't. It's a shorthand for reassignment. So : var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var {p: foo, q: bar} = o; really means foo = o.p; bar = o.q;

Comment: Exactly see the link I've added about [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

Answer (score 1):

In destructuring assignment, the *value* position becomes the variable to which the value is assigned.

When used in a position of declaration (like a function parameter), the names in the value position are declared in the current scope before being assigned the values.

As your example shows, a value position may also describe a nested object to be destructured, when then expects a value matching the described structure, which follows the same pattern above.

```js
// The data object
const data = {foo: "bar"};

// A destructuring declaration and assignment.
// The assignment target's structure matches that of the data
let {foo: localVar} = data;

console.log(localVar); // bar

// Same, but using the existing `localVar` variable with no new declaration.
({foo: localVar} = {foo: "baz"});

console.log(localVar); // baz
```