# What are those curly brackets within a function definition parameter?

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I have an Angular 5 project and I saw this Typescript code.

```
(method) CreateFlightComponent.handleSave({ currentValue, stepIndex }: {
    currentValue: Partial<Flight>;
    stepIndex: number;
}): void
```

---

Could anyone explain this part? Or is there any better way to express with a different syntax?

```
{ currentValue, stepIndex }: {
    currentValue: Partial<Flight>;
    stepIndex: number;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed parameter destructuring; the `currentValue` and `stepIndex` inside the first brackets are destructured into those arguments. After the colon the type is specified.

Comment: Related in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10804982/4174897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the `handleSave` function takes a complex type as input parameter, and returns void. The input type contains two properties:

- `currentValue` is of type  `Partial<Flight>`
- `stepIndex` is of type `number`.

Another way to express the same with a different syntax could be:

```
interface IHandleTypeParams {
    currentValue: Partial<Flight>;
    stepIndex: number;
}
```

and then use the interface instead:

```
CreateFlightComponent.handleSave( input:IHandleTypeParams): void
```

or with destructuring:

```
CreateFlightComponent.handleSave({ currentValue, stepIndex }: IHandleTypeParams): void
```

See the [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgSwOYAthQLxQN4CgoFQAmEAzsAgHYCGFA9pQFxTkBOVSANPoWNaaQiUkEVqQDCdAK6VgzSlIC2AI1G4AvrlxVgogGbUAxtACSACWqUicCABVwEAArVW1RaRw8Chqa1ZDgADVqOCkIZmdWChCAHnhkNAA+AG4vFl0wEysIAA95JVVWVM1cPRlDekoWBEUwGwBRHLc6iAAKKjApOShzS2s7B0i3UgBKZgA3OgQiT0IoQwZSOhsAOjg6JHbKTuAV8ghM7JyRtIXKJdX1zY6ulZ8-AODQiBOSssoKhAYoGT5DAGsOI1mjZWth5r5-LInmFOOkDlkSDkoOpmL0rDZ7JAhu4xlBJtNZoQzhcIGsNq19ockSc5iTlmSrq17lCgiEwq9cEA).

Read more about destructuring on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter).