# post.comments = post.comments.filter( ({ id }) => id !== req.params.comment_id ); -->Working of code

Tags: javascript

I am getting hard time understanding this code , I looked through internet but still couldn't get it.

```
post.comments = post.comments.filter(
  ({ id }) => id !== req.params.comment_id
);
```

I want to know how this code is actually working.

Comment: Which part is not clear? There are at least three different things here.

Comment: ({ id }) => id !== req.params.comment_id
This one

Comment: @YogeshwarSherawat it's an arrow function and return `true` or `false`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804982/where-can-i-get-info-on-the-object-parameter-syntax-for-javascript-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.filter` is a function of `Array` and it expects a callback function which returns a boolean value.

If the callback returns `true` item will be added in returned array. For `false`, it will be skipped.

---

`() => {}` is called Arrow function, which is similar to an anonymous function but does not have context and its inherited from defining function.

---

`({ id })` is a called as destructuring assignment where you can cherry-pick any property and create variable for it.

So the object `comment` instide `post.comments` will have `id` property and you are just fetching it from object

---

Your code would look something like this in ES5

```js
post.comments = post.comments.filter(function(comment) {
  var id = comment.id;
  return id !== req.params.comment_id;
})
```

---

#### References:

- [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)