# React component props wrapped inside braces?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component defined as :

```
type myType = anotherType<weirdType1, weirdType2, weirdType3>;

function weirdComponent({q}: myType)
```

And it's called like: `<weirdComponent {...myVar} />`, where `myVar` is an isinstance of `myType`.

- What does `{q}` mean inside weirdComponent function signature
- What does `{...myVar}` do?
- What kind of type is `myType` ?

Comment: You've asked several questions. `{q}` is parameter destructuring. `{...myVar}` is prop spreading. *"what kind of type is `myType`"* - it's the type whose definition is shown on the previous line, what do you mean *"what kind of type"*?

Comment: Title question is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31048953/3001761. First one in the body dupes https://stackoverflow.com/q/10804982/3001761. Third one I don't know what you're asking. I'd recommend bookmarking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript.

Answer (score 0):

> What does {q} mean inside weirdComponent function signature

Its argument [destructuring](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/destructuring).

> What does {...myVar} do?

Its [spreading attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)

> What kind of type is myType ?

Its `anotherType<weirdType1, weirdType2, weirdType3>;`. You can hover over it to view the details.