# understanding NodeJs typescript function body

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to understand what does the following piece of code does

```
export const extractSomeDto = ({
    _id,
    name,
    status
}: SomeDto): SomeDto =>
transformAttributes<SomeDto>({
    _id,
    name,
    status
});
```

**The function call is like this -**

```
extractSomeDto(JSON.parse(body))
```

**I could make out the following -**

1. the method `extractSomeDto` is exported for other files to call it
2. the method is going to return `: SomeDto`

**I have the following queries -**

What is the input for extractSomeDto?
Is it `SomeDto` or `_id, name, status`?

The method `extractSomeDto` is going to call another method called `transformAttributes`,
I can see `_id, name, status` passed as arguments, but I don't understand the `<SomeDto>` part

Comment: Input is supposed to be a `SomeDto`. `transformAttributes` is a generic function over a type. The type is specified using `<>`.

Comment: @MjZac SomeDto is input to transformAttributes? then the fields in the curly braces?

Comment: That is destructuring assignment. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down:

## `export`

```
    export const extractSomeDto = ({ _id, name, status }: SomeDto): SomeDto =>
//  ^^^^^^
      transformAttributes<SomeDto>({ _id, name, status });
```

> 1. the method `extractSomeDto` is exported for other files to call it

You are correct it will be [export from the current module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export).

Minor correction, this is a *function*, not a method. Methods belong on objects - you always call them as `something.someMethod()`. Functions don't have an object they are associated with, so they are essentially "free floating" and you can call them as `someFunction()`.

## Input parameter

```
export const extractSomeDto = ({ _id, name, status }: SomeDto): SomeDto =>
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    transformAttributes<SomeDto>({ _id, name, status });
```

The parameter this function takes is of type `SomeDto`, however, the properties `_id`, `name`, and `status` are going to be [destructured](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#object-destructuring). The handbook documentation shows a variable declaration but [it can also be used for parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804982/where-can-i-get-info-on-the-object-parameter-syntax-for-javascript-functions).

In essence, it just takes the values of those three properties from the input and assigns them to a variable with the same name. It's easier than doing `input._id`, `input.name`, and `input.status`.

## Return type

```
export const extractSomeDto = ({ _id, name, status }: SomeDto): SomeDto =>
//                                                              ^^^^^^^
    transformAttributes<SomeDto>({ _id, name, status });
```

> 2. the method is going to return `: SomeDto`

You are again correct - the return type is `SomeDto` again. (reminder  it's a function, not a method).

So, the input and output are the same type of object.

## Generic function call

```
export const extractSomeDto = ({ _id, name, status }: SomeDto): SomeDto =>
    transformAttributes<SomeDto>({ _id, name, status });
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The function will call [a generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) called `transformAttributes`. The signature of that function must be something like `function <T>transformAttributes()` where `T` would be the generic type argument. In your case, the type argument is `SomeDto`. What *exactly* that determines for the function depends on the implementation although it's one of

- The parameter(s) type, e.g., `function <T>transformAttributes(input: T)`
- The return type, e.g., `function <T>transformAttributes(): T`
- Both the input and the return type `function <T>transformAttributes(input: T): T`

## Input argument for `transformAttributes()`

```
export const extractSomeDto = ({ _id, name, status }: SomeDto): SomeDto =>
    transformAttributes<SomeDto>({ _id, name, status });
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is [object property shorthand syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414766/javascript-object-literal-what-exactly-is-a-b-c). It's equivalent to `{ _id: _id, name: name, status: status  }`. In other words, it creates properties from these three variables where for each the name is the name of the variable and the value is the value of the variable.

## Return value of `transformAttributes` and `extractSomeDto`

Finally, a quick mention - since the code is using an arrow function and is body is not wrapped in curly brackets `{}` then implicitly the return value is whatever the body returns. This means that `extractSomeDto` returns the result of `transformAttributes<SomeDto>({ _id, name, status })` when called.

Comment: why were `_id, name, status` destructured and then put into `SomeDto`? Can I just accept SomeDto as an input to extractSomeDto? Will this work `export const extractSomeDto = (dto SomeDto): SomeDto => transformAttributes<>(dto);`

Comment: Maybe it would work, maybe not. I don't really know, since I don't know what `SomeDto` contains. If it's really only just these three, then you can do it. If it has more properties, then perhaps the destructuring is to get rid of them and get a "minimally viable `SomeDto`". I also don't really know what `transformAttributes` does. I *assume* the signature is `function <T>transformAttributes(input: any): T` and it just changes all values in an object or something but that's just a guess based on the name and how it's used.

Answer (score 1):

**Function Name**: `extractSomeDto`

**Function Parameters**: `{_id,name,status}: SomeDtoan`. This means that the function takes in an object of type SomeDtoan and destructures it to pull out the following fields: _id, name, status.

**Function Return type**: `SomeDto`

Function body: the function is returning the result of

```
transformAttributes<SomeDto>({
    _id,
    name,
    status
});
```

Here is the same function, rewritten to be a little easier to understand.

```
export const extractSomeDto = (inputObject: SomeDto): SomeDto => {
   const _id = inputObject._id;
   const name = inputObject.name;
   const status = inputObject.status;

   return transformAttributes<SomeDto>({_id, name, status});
}
```